# AngularJS : watching an expression consisting of variable and function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive, watch

everyone! Thanks in advance!

I have the following problem: I want to watch an input field's attribute, which at the same time is my directive's name, to focus and select the value when
a) the area the input field is in was activated or when
b) and error from the server occured.

Here the code of the input field:

```
<input type="email"
    data-focus-and-select="areas.contactInformationEditEmail || hasServerErrorsEmail()" />
```

Here the code of the controller function:

```
$scope.hasServerErrorsEmail = function() {
    return !!($scope.notifications.errors.email.empty ||
            $scope.notifications.errors.email.invalid ||
            $scope.notifications.errors.email.illegal ||
            $scope.notifications.errors.email.blacklisted ||
            $scope.notifications.errors.email.conflict);
};
```

If an server error occurred, one of these notification errors is set to true.
Here the code of the directive:

```
angular.module('myApp.directive').directive('focusAndSelect', function() {
    'use strict';
    return {
        scope: { focusAndSelect: '=' },
        link: function(scope, element) {
            scope.$watch('focusAndSelect', function(newValue) {
                if (newValue && !element.hasClass('ng-hide')) {
                    element[0].focus();
                    element[0].setSelectionRange(0, element[0].value.length);
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

There are three scenarios:

1) The "focus and select" works when I change the form into editable mode, so that `areas.contactInformationEditEmail` is set to true.
2) The "focus and select" won't work when I receive an server error. The input field is not focused and selected.
3) But when I remove the `areas.contactInformationEditEmail` from the expression `areas.contactInformationEditEmail || hasServerErrorsEmail()`, the "focus and select" works for the error receiving input field.

I have no idea. Is it maybe a problem to watch and variable and and function call at once?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you use '=' in the isolated scope of the directive it binds to a property in the parent scope, it's not possible to bind to an evaluated expression.

try this instead:

```
<input type="email"
    data-focus-and-select="{{areas.contactInformationEditEmail || hasServerErrorsEmail()}}" />
```

and your directive:

```
angular.module('myApp.directive').directive('focusAndSelect', function() {
    'use strict';
    return {
        scope: { focusAndSelect: '=' },
        link: function(scope, element) {
            scope.$watch('focusAndSelect', function(newValue) {
                if (newValue && !element.hasClass('ng-hide') && scope.$eval(newValue)) {
                    element[0].focus();
                    element[0].setSelectionRange(0, element[0].value.length);
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

you need the $eval because the value will be a String and you want to get it's boolean value.

here's a simplified [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/We89C/4/) to demonstrate it.